# Mysql - Get row with lowest relation count

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I have two mysql tables:

1. **Teacher** with columns `id, name, age`
2. **Student** with columns `name, age, teacher_id` where `teacher_id` is the id of the teacher to whom the student is assigned.

Now, the load amongst the teachers should be equally distributed. Everytime a new student is added to the system, I need to assign it a teacher who's the least busy i.e. has least number of students assigned to it.

Is there a really fast way of doing this? Initially, i thought i could use a `group by teacher_id` and sort it by the count to get it. However, this leaves out teachers that don't have any student assigned to them yet.

If we're using joins, how will the performance be if the student table has 1million rows?

Answer (score 1):

You just need an outer join to include the teachers with zero students.

```
select t.id, t.name
from teacher t
left join student s on t.id = s.teacher_id
group by t.id
order by count(s.name)
limit 1
```

You can use denormalization (a column with the precomputed number of students per teacher), however, it is a bad habit and I would not recommend it if it is not really inevitable.

Comment: how would its performance be if i have some 100k records in student table?
And yes, i forgot to mention the id column in teacher table

Comment: if you indeed group by on a PRIMARY KEY than the query is correct

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "really fast way" of doing this, then I would suggest a small redesign.

Implement triggers to maintain the current student count for all the teachers.  This would be a new column, `student_count`, say.

Put an index on the student count and simply do:

```
select t.*
from teachers t
order by student_count asc
limit 1;
```

I am not a big fan of triggers, but when they are useful, they really are useful.  You have a performance problem and a need to aggregate data along a hierarchy.  You need triggers for `insert`, `update`, and `delete` on the students.